# How to make Java Swing Radio Buttons unselectable but not greyed out?

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I am developing a Java Swing App, and I want to use `JRadioButton` objects to show state.  I don't want the user to have the ability to select them.  If I use the button's `.setEnabled(false)` method, the radio button is greyed out.

I don't want the Radio Button to grey out.  Is there a way to override this?

Comment: *"I don't want the Radio Button to grey out."*  And I (as the hypothetical end user) don't want controls on the GUI that appear ..controllable, yet are not!  How about honoring the 'path of least surprise' and *not* doing what you are attempting?

Comment: *"I don't want the Radio Button to grey out"* As another "hypothetical end user" -  why?

Answer (score -1):

Well You Could Do Something Like:

```
boolean rButtonEnabled = false;
JRadioButton rButton = new JRadioButton();

rButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            rdbtnNewRadioButton.setSelected(rButtonEnabled);

        }

});
```

It's not the prettyist solution, but I hope it helps.
To store the new value perhaps you can create a new class extending **JRadioButton**.

While this does not use the .setEnabled(), it is effectively the same

Comment: *"It's not the prettyist solution [...]."* Yes, that's right. It's hacky and subversive. The downvoter probably agrees.

Comment: @Radiodef While the code may look a bit extreme for such a measure, the actual display of it works perfectly.